# Properly delimit String in Buffer

Tags: java, string, apache

I was wondering how to properly delimit a String in a Buffer in Java (using IoBuffers in Apache MINA). Here's some example code:

**Client Side**

```
IoBuffer buffer = IoBuffer.allocate(100);
buffer.putString("username");
buffer.putString("password");
buffer.flip();
session.write(buffer);
```

Since I'm putting one string after another in the string, it'll be treated as one string when the server receives the buffer.

**Server Side**

```
IoBuffer buffer = (IoBuffer) message;
String username = buffer.getString(Charset.forName("UTF-8").newDecoder());
String password = buffer.getString(Charset.forName("UTF-8").newDecoder());
```

That will throw some kind of Exception on the second getString(), because the program thinks it got the whole entire String (because those two strings put together count as one string).

How should I properly delimit these two strings? The obvious approach is to do something like:

"username:password"

and on server side:

```
String[] args = buffer.getString(Charset.forName("UTF-8").newDecoder()).split(":", 2);
String username = args[0];
String password = args[1];
```

Is that the best way to do this? Or is there a more proper way to delimit these two strings?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You have many ways : usually  using '`\n`' is the best [ with readLine() or nextLine() ] , '`\t`' sometime like in CSV

You can also use specific character not in your LANG, like accent not in ASCII '`¨`', or symbol like '`§`' '`µ`'

You can also , the non printable BELL `char delim = '7';`

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way is to use a delimiter character but perhaps not a `:` since that is used in search paths and such. A semicolon `;` is probably a better delimiter even if it doesn't look as good.

Thats the approach I use in my applications atleast.